# Приведение строки к маске ввода

Tags: c#, .net

От пользователя приходит некий код, и он сравнивается с форматом кода для каждой конкретной страны(он может быть разным), и если его можно привести к соответствующей маске, то он приводится к ней. Например приходит код 4543dx и проверяется можно ли привести его к маске NNNN-lL, где N- цифра, l - строчная буква, L - заглавная. Эта маска подходит, значит сохраняем значение 4543-dX.

Есть такой вот метод, который генерирует паттерн, который принимает маску

```
 private string ParseCode(string format)
    {
        if (format == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string pattern = @"";

        for (int i = 0; i < format.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (format[i])
            {
                case 'N':
                    pattern += "[0-9]";
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    pattern += "[A-Z]";
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    pattern += "[a-z]";
                    break;
            }
        }
        return pattern;
    }
```

Что делать дальше не совсем понимаю. Как бы вы это реализовали?

Comment: Маска должна меняться "на лету" (без перекомпиляции), или она статична и не будет меняться?